# Quartus fitter takes a lot of RAM

Tags: opencl, fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

I am recently doing an Altera OpenCl project on FPGA and when the compilation moves into quartus_fit. It takes 80+% of the RAM on my PC(I have 32GB). And the fitting will crush after around ten hours. Is a fitting supposed to take this amount of resource? I don't know how to resolve it, is quartus fitter guaranteed to finish if the synthesis is successful? Thanks

Comment: For which device are you generating the bitstream?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen `quartus_fit` consuming around 110GB. So in case of building large designs, it will most likely fail due to insufficient RAM.

Answer (score 0):

The 17.1 is the most stable release of OpenCL SDK and Quartus Pro tools so far. If it is crashing in other releases - I feel your pain. If you compiling for a 1150 Arria 10 'they' recommend 64GB of RAM. We are able to compile 50% full 1150 FPGA in 32GB in the company on multiple projects. The 10+ hours used to be normal in 13.1 but 250 MHz small kernel should compile in under 2 hours. Large memory indicate usually a problem in the code or BSP. Look at your timing results in the TimeQuest after OpenCL flow completes - takes just few minutes - if you have A LOT of violations this usually indicates that something is wrong.